Section View of an Object
I came across a question that indicated this diagram (as shown) as the correct section view of the object cut along the C-C line.

I have trouble understanding why the section view is as such. When seen from the side, shouldn't the view look like this (see below) instead?


The section view and isometric express that there is a bottom. The view on the lower left is just not showing tangents to the fillet, and the view on the upper left is not showing hidden lines. A matter of correctness in these assignments is more about finding contradictions in possible answers- find an answer that does not contradict the given data. In this case your proposed section contradicts the isometric and its 3 circles. Naturally, its not the only answer. One could come up with a miniscule (small enough yo be obscured by line weight) feature for the third circle in the isometric.

the C-C section shows what is required in the final product ... it is not derived from any other view

Your version would not generate the 3rd line in the hole in the isometric. But frankly, neither does the preferred solution.

The section view you are suggesting would have an isometric view that would look like this:

The section they are proposing would have an isometric view that would look like this:

When colour and background information get added things are much clearer and you can see why the two circular lines in the black and white isometric view are rather confusing. The one that looks to be about halfway through the center hole is the start of the fillet and the one at the bottom of the hole which could be taken as the outside edge is actually the bottom of the fillet where it becomes tangent with the bottom of the center hole.
